# Editing Django Wagtail Context

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, wagtail

I am trying to add additional context to a home page model pulling from a separate app.

The function already in the model is already handling a contact form on the page. I want to add blog posts from a portfolio app.

Here is my function within my model:

```py
    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from contact.forms import ContactForm
        from portfolio.models import PortfolioDetailPage

        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['posts'] = PortfolioDetailPage.objects.live().public()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                  //form stuff
                try:
                   //more form stuff
                except Exception as e:
                  //more form stuff
                return render(request, 'contact/contact_page_landing.html', {
                    'page': self,
                    'contact': contact
                })
        else:
            form = ContactForm()

        return render(request, 'home/home_page.html', {
            'context': context,
            'page': self,
            'form': form
        })
```

In my template, I have the following:

```html
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        {% image post.gallery_main_image fill-250x250 as blog_img %}
                    <div class="latest__item">
                        <img src="{{ blog_img.url }}" alt="">
                        <h4><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.gallery_name }}</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

However, I am not getting any `posts` in my context. The form works properly. It seems this is an issue with the `serve` function in Wagtail already pulling my context and somehow I am not returning it properly but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` is meant to be the dictionary you pass as the final argument to `render`. You're passing it as a *member* of that dictionary instead, which would mean that the `posts` is available on the template as the variable `context.posts` - this probably isn't what you want.

`page` is already included in the initial context returned by `super().get_context(request)`, which means the only missing piece is to add `form`:

```
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'home/home_page.html', context)
```